# How to prove this inequalities involving measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$ be a measure space and $E_i\in\mathcal M$. Then I want to check that:

1) $\mu(\liminf E_i) \le \liminf \mu(E_i)$.

2) If $\mu(\bigcup_i E_i)<\infty$, then $\mu(\limsup E_i) \ge \limsup \mu(E_i)$.

So I know that the infimum is $\bigcap_i E_i$ and the supremum is $\bigcup_i E_i$, the thing is that for the first part, for example I've got that

Since $\bigcap_i E_i$ is the infimum I can conclude that $\mu(\bigcap_i E_i) \le \mu (E_i)$ for all $i$ but then, How can I include the limit in this inequality?.

The same for the other inequality, and I think I am doing something wrong there, since with this approach I won't use that  $\mu(\bigcup_i E_i)<\infty$.

So, Can someone help me to prove those assertions in the right way please?

Thanks in advance.

**Using @martini's answer, How can I conclude?**

> > I have notice in @martini's answer that since we are taking $$ \limsup_i \left(\bigcup_j E_j - E_i\right)$$ in $i$, then we have that
>
> $$ \limsup_i \left(\bigcup_j E_j - E_i\right) = \bigcup_j E_j +
> > \limsup_i (-E_i)$$
>
> therefore
>
> $$\bigcup_j E_j + \limsup_i (-E_i)=\bigcup_j E_j - \liminf_i (E_i)$$
>
> The thing is that, Why do this arrive at the second inequality?

Thanks.

Comment: This is Fatou's lemma.

Comment: ok, jajaja let me check that. Just a second.

Comment: Well, That lemma talks about integrals, so I think I am not allowed to use that yet :)

Comment: So then @MichaelHardy, What can be done?

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**. (1) Recall that 
$$ \liminf E_i = \bigcup_j \bigcap_{i \ge j} E_i, \quad \limsup E_i = \bigcap_j \bigcup_{i\ge j} E_i $$
(2) For every $j$, we have, as you note correctly 
$$ \mu\left(\bigcap_{i \ge j} E_i\right) \le \mu(E_i), \quad i \ge j $$
this gives
$$ \mu\left(\bigcap_{i \ge j} E_i\right) \le \inf_{i\ge j} \mu(E_i) $$
Now use that $(\bigcap_{i \ge j} E_i)_j$ is increasing.

(3) Having established 1., use it to prove 2., noting that 
$$ \limsup_i \left(\bigcup_j E_j - E_i\right) = \bigcup_j E_j - \liminf_i E_i $$

Comment: I have a question, Why is $\bigcap E_i$ increasing?

Comment: Just another thing, can you clarify the notation for lim sup and lim inf please, just the first equalities you have because I've got confused a little bit :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once I have notice your last observation, How can I conclude?

Comment: So then, what can be done?

Comment: Re: Why is $\cap E_i $ increasing? Let $S_j=\cap_{i \geq j} E_i$ .Then $S_j=E_j\cap S_{j+1}\subset S_{j+1}.$

Comment: right, but then how do you arrive at the second inequality ? Thanks