# Prove an outer measure inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For each $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ we define

$$\displaystyle m^*(A) = \inf \Big\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty (b_i - a_i): A\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (a_i,b_i)\Big\}.$$

Then I want to see that  $\displaystyle m^*\Big(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\Big) \le \sum_{j=1}^\infty m^*(A_j).$

Well, I think this is tricky, because I was trying to use that if we have $A \subset B$ then $m^*(A)\le m^*(B)$ but the thing is that we only know that $A_j \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j$for each $j$ and I can't figure out only by watching the definition of $m^*$ that the inequality holds, because we can have a pathological case where this weak argument fails.

Can someone help me to prove this result please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $j$ take a collection $\big\{ (a_i^j,b_i^j) \big\}_i$ covering $A_j$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty (b_i^j - a_i^j) < m^*(A_j) + \frac{\epsilon}{2^j}$. This is just the definition of infimum for each $m^*(A_j)$.

The collection $\big\{ (a_i^j,b_i^j) \big\}_{i,j}$ covers $\bigcup_{j}A_j$ and you have $$m^*\Big(\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j\Big) \leq \sum_{i,j}^\infty (b_i^j - a_i^j) < \sum_{j=1}^\infty m^*(A_j) + \epsilon$$

The result follows because $\epsilon$ can be any positive number.

Comment: Why do you have powers in the intervals?

Comment: these are not powers, just superscripts

Comment: Ok, so Why are they there?, I mean, I find them confusing :) I apologize for that

Comment: you need countably many collections, each of which is countable, the usual way to do this is to use double indices to write each open interval, one index for the collection, the other index for the interval within the collection.

Comment: Ok, so you mean there are $i$ intervals that cover the $j-th$ set right?

Comment: the $j$-th set is covered by countably many intervals, but they are numbered using the $i$ variable. Then use that the union of countably many countable sets is countable, so putting all these collections and their intervals together results in a bugger, yet countable collection of intervals.

Comment: You define $\displaystyle A_j=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} (a_i^j,b_i^j)$ and each $A_j$ is a cover for $A$, so apply infimum property to each $A_j$ to get a bound for $m^{*}(\bigcup A_j)$

Comment: Can you clarify your comment @user160738 please?

Comment: Can you help me with this one please http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536983/how-to-prove-this-inequalities-involving-measures ? Thanks in advance

Comment: How should I visualize (think about) the collections of collections? I'm having trouble imagining this.

Comment: @jjjjjj  Note that $\big\{\big\{ (a_i^j,b_i^j) \big\}_i\big\}_j \neq \big\{ (a_i^j,b_i^j) \big\}_{i,j}$, the RHS is not a collection of collections.