# The generators of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that $\mathcal B_\mathbb{R}$ is generated by each of the following:

$$\mathcal E_1 = \{(a,b): a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a<b\}$$

$$\mathcal E_2 = \{[a,b]: a,b\in \mathbb{R}, a<b\}$$
    $$\mathcal E_3 = \{(a,b]: a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a<b\}$$
    $$\mathcal E_4 = \{[a,b): a,b\in \mathbb{R}, a<b\}$$
    $$\mathcal E_5 = \{(a,\infty): a\in \mathbb{R}\}$$
    $$\mathcal E_6 = \{(-\infty,a): a\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
    $$\mathcal E_7 = \{[a,\infty): a\in \mathbb{R}\}$$
    $$\mathcal E_8 = \{(-\infty,a]: a\in \mathbb{R}\}$$

So the easiest way to prove this is by contention, this is

$$\mathcal B_\mathbb{R} \subset M(\mathcal E_1) \subset M(\mathcal E_2) \subset \ldots M(\mathcal E_8) \subset \mathcal B_\mathbb{R}$$

But the thing is that I can't figure out how to prove those contentions, I have already proved that $\mathcal B_\mathbb{R} \subset M(\mathcal E_1) \subset M(\mathcal E_2) $ using the trick that $(a,b)= \bigcup_n [a+1/n, b+1/n]$, and $ M(\mathcal E_6) \subset M(\mathcal E_7) $ since they are only the complement, to get that $M(\mathcal E_5) \subset M(\mathcal E_6)$ I tried to do the following $(a, \infty)=\bigcup_n [a+1/n, \infty)= \bigcup_n \mathbb{R}-(-\infty, a+1/n)$, and to see that $M(\mathcal E_3) \subset M(\mathcal E_4)$ I wrote $(a,b]= \bigcup_n [a+1/n,\infty) \bigcap (-\infty,b]$ but I think I am not allowed to do this.

I have been trying to find how to write a closed set in terms of a open set (of course not using the complemet, since I can't take the complement only of a part of the interval, I want to this trick to have the contention of $M(\mathcal E_2) \subset M(\mathcal E_3)$ for example), but I wasn't lucky with that.

So can someone help me with this contentions please (and to verify that he ones I did are correct please)?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Just a slight correction: you want $(a, b) = \cup_n [a + \frac 1 n, b - \frac 1 n]$. To prove $M(E_2) \subseteq M(E_3)$, just write $[a, b] = \cap_n (a-\frac 1 n, b]$.

Comment: And how can I get the other contentions? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Don't be too strict about proving the inclusions in that order since it's obvious all $M(E_i) \subseteq B_\mathbb{R}$. For example, I'd prove that $M(E_2) \subseteq M(E_4)$ in exactly the same way, so we're done with $M(E_1) = M(E_2) = M(E_3) = M(E_4) = B_\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The thing is that otherwise I have to prove a mess like a contention of everyone with everyone :), That was the idea, What do you had in mind ? I mean, do you have an easier way to prove this?

Comment: using $\mathcal E_5$, do you get $\bigcup (a, \infty) \cap \mathbb{R}-(b-1/n, \infty)$ right?

Answer (score 3):

All the generating sets in all of the $\mathcal{E}_i$ are Borel, so the $\sigma$-algebras generated by the $\mathcal{E}_i$ are subsets of $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$.

The Borel sets are by definition generated by the open sets, and all open sets are at most countable unions of open intervals, so we are done for $\mathcal{E}_1$.

So you just have to show that open intervals are in all the generated $\sigma$-algebras from $\mathcal{E}_i$.

E.g. if we have all $[a,b)$, then we have all open intervals $(c,d)$ as $\cup_{n \in I} [c+\frac{1}{n}, d)$ (where $I$ is the set of all $n$ so large that $\frac{1}{n} < d-c$). So all $\mathcal{E}_4$ generates all intervals, and so all Borel sets.

For unbounded: $(a,\rightarrow)$ generates all sets of the form $(\leftarrow, b]$ by complementation, so so all sets $(a, b]$ by intersection. Then we apply what we already know. The others are almost identical.

Comment: So your idea is to show that the open intervals are in all the generated $\sigma$-algebras right?

Comment: Yes. And once you have shown it for one type, you can reduce it to those other types as well

Comment: I don't understand that reduction, do you mean that I have to prove that the close intervals are in each of the $\sigma$-algebras, and so on ?

Comment: No, once you know that all $[a,b)$ are in a generated algebra then so are all Borel sets (so you are done), so we can reduce the unbounded onces to the bounded ones, becaue we showed that they contain one of the bounded generating familes 1-4. Etc.

Answer (score 2):

The main idea is that you can get one type of intervals from another type by using the $\sigma$-algebra operations: (countable) Union, Intersection, Complement (and hence Difference) of sets. For example, if you are starting with open intervals $(a,b)$ then you could get left-closed intervals simply by taking $(c,a)\setminus (c,b)=[b,a)$ for $c<b<a$. 
To get open intervals from half-closed let $(a, b) = \cup_n [a + \frac 1 n, b)$ similar to what @CWL indicated in a comment (and for this you use the $\sigma$ in $\sigma$-algebra). From infinite intervals like $(a,\infty)$ you get finite $(a,b]=(a,\infty)\setminus (b,\infty)$, etc.

Comment: Right, but the thing is, How can I get the other ones? Can you help me with that? thanks in advance :)

Comment: you / is difference right?

Comment: I added some details, you could use the same ideas adjusted for each particular case as appropriate. Think about it, and ask if you have a problem with a specific case, they are all done in a similar way.

Comment: Ok, :) let me check, and can you help me with this one please  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1536983/how-to-prove-this-inequalities-involving-measures?

Comment: I do use $\setminus$, \, not /, for set-difference, \ is the standard notation which I assume you have seen if you post a question about algebra of sets. I did not use / in my post, I do not see why you refer to /.

Comment: sorry, that is right :), I hope you can take a look to my other question in fact :)

Comment: that other question has already been answered, you need to put a bit more effort to read the answer. The $\bigcap E_i$ are increasing, because the fewer sets you intersect, the bigger the intersection. Don't ask for every single detail, try to figure some on your own. (That is, do ask for every single detail, but first of all ask yourself, and figure the easy answers on your own.)

Comment: Right, the thing is that I have already figure out that, my question is how to conclude :)

Comment: I have been thinking of it , and I can't figure how to conclude with the hint given In that answer :(

Comment: take a break, it will come back to you, you will figure it. Review the definitions.

Comment: Well I'll try that (I have been trying to figure out this about hours :( ), If I have further questions about this post and the other one, Can I let you know?

Comment: Is the difference in the algebra? Why is that?

Comment: The complement is in the algebra, and the difference could be expressed in terms of complement and intersection. $A\setminus B=A\cap(\mathbb R\setminus B$).